# YAML::Emitter.size() different from strlen(YAML::Emitter.c_str())

Tags: c++, yaml, yaml-cpp

Using YAML::Emitter I sometimes get YAML::Emitter.size() to return a bigger size than strlen(YAML::Emitter.c_str()).
e.g.

```
YAML::Emitter em;
em << something;
if (em.size() > strlen(em.c_str())
{
    std::cout << "WOW " << em.size() << " > " << strlen(em.c_str());
}
```

This creates issues when writing the yaml text to a buffer:

```
char* buff = malloc(em.size());
memcpy(buff, em.c_str(), em.size());
```

because the extra characters at the end fail the yaml parser on the other side that reads this buffer.

Thanks!

Comment: `strlen` will stop at the first null terminator. Do you have any of those? See related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028448/strlen-gives-larger-number-than-the-size-of-an-array

Comment: @Marc No null terminators - I get the full expected yaml as string with em.c_str(). But em.size() returns a bigger size (by 3-8 characters) causing extra characters to be copied.

Comment: You should probably include a full example that fails, including data being emitted.

Comment: This might be a bug in yaml-cpp. Could you file an issue on the github page with a complete example?

Comment: I noticed that this issue happens when the yaml is relatively large (> 4kbytes). For small buffers, size() matches strlen() exactly. I will try to come up with a reproducible example.